# Cambiar el valor a una variable en una View al ejecutar un funcion Javascript dentro de un DropDownListFor en ASP.NET (Cache?)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un `DropDownListFor` en una `view`, el cual al seleccionar uno, ejecuta una funcion con `Javascript`usando `ajax` `JQuery` para poder mostrar una etiqueta correspondiente de ese `DropDownListFor`, ejemplo si selecciono ***ACEITE***, debe aparecer arriba del input la etiqueta con la descripcion que seria ***Cambio de aceite y filtro***, pero no lo hace, se queda con el valor que inicia que es el guion (**-**)

**Anexo Imagen1**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es como si quedare en cache la `view`, al hacer debug me di cuenta que la descripcion al cual llame etiqueta si me lo esta trayendo mas no lo cambia

**Anexo Imagen2**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Anexo Codigo Controlador**

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, int tiposervicio = -1)
    {
        try
        {
            //---------- LISTA DE SERVICIO ------------//

            List<_Servicio> lst_Servicio = new List<_Servicio>();
            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            using (SqlConnection CON = Class.ConexionBD.conexionDBTienda("TIENDA"))
            {
                string sql = $"SELECT ID, NOMBRE_SERVICIO FROM Servicios";
                using (SqlCommand COM = new SqlCommand(sql, CON))
                {
                    reader = COM.ExecuteReader();
                }
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lst_Servicio.Add(new _Servicio()
                    {
                        ID = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        NOMBRE_SERVICIO = reader.GetString(1),
                    });
                }
                List<SelectListItem> itemsServicio = lst_Servicio.ConvertAll(d =>
                {
                    return new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = d.NOMBRE_SERVICIO.ToString(),
                        Value = d.ID.ToString(),
                        Selected = false
                    };
                });
                ViewBag.servicio = itemsServicio;
            }

            string etiqueta = "-";
            reader = null;
            //---------- LISTA DE ETIQUETA ------------//
            using (SqlConnection CON = Class.ConexionBD.conexionDBTienda("TIENDA"))
            {
                string sql = $"SELECT ETIQUETA FROM SERVICIOS WHERE ID = {tiposervicio}";

                using (SqlCommand COM = new SqlCommand(sql, CON))
                {
                    reader = COM.ExecuteReader();
                }
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    etiqueta = reader.GetString(0);
                }
                ViewBag.etiqueta = etiqueta;
                ViewBag.id = id;
            }
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Anexo Codigo View**

```
@model Models.ViewModels.Registro_Servicio
@{
    List<SelectListItem> servicio = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.servicio;
    int id = ViewBag.id;
    string etiqueta = ViewBag.etiqueta;
}

<h2>Servicio</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index_Servicio", "Servicio", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="@id" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>Servicios:</span>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID_SERVICIO, servicio, "SELECCIONE", new { @class = "form-control", id = "tiposervicio", style = "margin-right: 15px; width:200px; height:30px", onchange = "Index( id,tiposervicio, this)" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>@etiqueta</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.DATA1, "", new { @class = "form-control", style = "margin-right: 15px; width:400px; height:30px", maxlength = "8", onkeypress = "return justNumbers(event);" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.DATA1, "", new { @class = "red" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
}
<hr />
<script>

    var urlr = "https://localhost:44323/";

    function Index() {
        var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
        var tiposervicio = document.getElementById('tiposervicio');
        var value = tiposervicio.options[tiposervicio.selectedIndex].value;
        $.ajax({
            url: urlr + "Tabl/Index",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id: id, tiposervicio: value }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Que pudiera estar fallando en mi codigo que no muestra o cambia el nombre de la etiqueta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, yo haría eso de la siguiente manera, crea una acción solo para el cambio de ese label, por ejemplo:

```
public ActionResult LabelChange(int id){

string etiqueta = "-";
        reader = null;
        //---------- LISTA DE ETIQUETA ------------//
        using (SqlConnection CON = Class.ConexionBD.conexionDBTienda("TIENDA"))
        {
            string sql = $"SELECT ETIQUETA FROM SERVICIOS WHERE ID = {tiposervicio}";

            using (SqlCommand COM = new SqlCommand(sql, CON))
            {
                reader = COM.ExecuteReader();
            }
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                etiqueta = reader.GetString(0);
            }
        }
return Content(etiqueta);
}
```

Y en la vista en el script:

```
$(function ()
{
    $("#tiposervicio").change(function (){
        var tiposervicio = $('#tiposervicio option:selected').val();
        var data = {tipoServicioId = tiposervicio};
        var url = "@Url.Action("LabelChange", "NombreControlador")";
        $.get(url, data).done(function (data){
            $("#labelChange").text(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Y puedes usar en el label de la siguiente manera:

```
@Html.Label("-", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "labelChange"})
```

Prueba y me dices, el inconveniente debe estar en que para que ese valor cambie en esa etiqueta asi como lo estas aplicando, seria necesario recargar ese campo, y al hacerlo con el mismo metodo que inicias esa vista estas recargandola toda. Quedo atento y me comentas amigo, trate de mantener mas o menos la idea de como sacas el dato en el controlador.

Comment: Tampoco me funciono, fue muy buena la idea pero me falla

Comment: Muestra que error te sale, porque ese código yo lo saque de una aplicación personal y esta funcional bro

Comment: coloque el codigo tal cual pero no hace la invocacion al controlador

Comment: En el metodo de js esta hecho con jquery, si no tienes jquery simplemente pasa el metodo al js normal con el onchange bro o añade la referencia de jquery y listo, si le das inspeccionar te debe estar saliendo el error porque no tienes jquery intanciado, solo es eso.

Comment: @MicaelRipoll, pude hacerlo pero usando solo javascript y cree una funcion EventListener para cada vez que pulse mi despegable

Comment: Vale amigo, si también era posible de esa manera, me alegra que ya lo solucionaras y que de algo haya servido, bendiciones.